# CFile::Remove, removed a file from directory but the file is not available

Tags: c++, mfc

I have mfc application which deletes a file on click of button, the file is getting deleted, but its not available in Recycle Bin. I want the file to be available in Recycle bin. How can I do it.

```
file.Remove((LPCTSTR)csFilePath.GetBuffer());
```

Please help me.

Here is the code of what i have implemented in my class. Please tell me were am i going wrong.
Here is the code for more details

```
void CUtility::DeleteSelectedFile(CString csFilePath)
  { // ensure double-null ending
  TCHAR szBuffer[MAX_PATH + 2] = {0};
  _tcscpy_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), (LPCTSTR)csFilePath.GetBuffer());
    int nResult;
    // set up struct
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT pStruct;
    pStruct.hwnd = NULL;
    pStruct.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
    pStruct.pFrom = szBuffer;
    pStruct.pTo = NULL;
    pStruct.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOERRORUI;
    pStruct.fAnyOperationsAborted = false;
    pStruct.hNameMappings = NULL;
    pStruct.lpszProgressTitle = NULL;
    // perform the delete
    nResult = SHFileOperation(&pStruct);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example function using [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx):

```
void CImageRectanglesDlg::DeleteToRecycle(const CString &szFilename)
{
    // ensure double-null ending
    TCHAR szBuffer[MAX_PATH + 2] = {0};
    _tcscpy_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), szFilename);

    // ensure double-null termination
    int nLen = szFilename.GetLength();
    szBuffer[nLen] = _T('\0');
    szBuffer[nLen + 1] = _T('\0');

    // set up struct
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT pStruct;
    pStruct.hwnd = NULL;
    pStruct.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
    pStruct.pFrom = szBuffer;
    pStruct.pTo = NULL;
    pStruct.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NO_UI;
    pStruct.fAnyOperationsAborted = false;
    pStruct.hNameMappings = NULL;
    pStruct.lpszProgressTitle = NULL;

    // perform the delete
    int nRes = SHFileOperation(&pStruct);
    ASSERT(!nRes);
}
```

Note that you have to carefully construct the `pFrom` member of the struct as this is actually a *list* of pathnames and must be terminated with a double NULL. You can supply multiple pathnames in this buffer, each delimited with a single NULL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping with the code snippet. I have used it in my code but am unable to delete the file. The function `SHFileOperation(&pStruct);` returns non-zero value.

Comment: It returns ERROR CODE 124.

Comment: Yes the file path of the file is same as you have mentioned. Then to its not deleting the file.

Comment: Please check the code which i have added to the question and let me know what am I doing wrong in it..

Comment: Ok Thanx mate, I'll be waiting for your reply.

Comment: @user2978612 - ok, I found the problem - for some reason, the double-null terminator was getting corrupted. I'm not sure why yet - it may be a side-effect of `_tcscpy_s` in a Debug build, but I've updated the code now to something that works in both Debug *and* Release. See what you think.

Comment: @user2978612 - ok, just add `FOF_NO_UI` to the flags (I've updated my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, MFC doesn't provide support for Recycled Bin, so the right way is to use WinAPI --> [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx) function with flag FOF_ALLOWUNDO.

Sample code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

SHFILEOPSTRUCT fo = {0};
fo.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
fo.pFrom = filename; // specify full path with doubled zero at the end (\0\0)
fo.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_ALLOWUNDO;

if (SHFileOperation(&fo) == 0)
  return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done in using the  SHFileOperation and filling accordingly the  FILEOPSTRUCT Parameter. You must use the  FO_DELETE Parameter.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)